# Parsing JSON into C-Style char array with Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, c, json, cordova

While developing a plugin for cordova, I've run into some trouble parsing JSON-Objects that contain C-Style char arrays. The JSON Object looks like:

```
{
    UUID: "E6DACE68-5F93-4127-AD80-EE8C4AF4D539",
    primary: true,
    characteristics: [
        {
            properties:"CBCharacteristicPropertyRead",
            value: [0x51,0xA2,0x5F,0xFF],
            permissions:"CBAttributePermissionsReadable",
            UUID: "54ADDF4D-771A-4029-81FF-20F36210D2F2"
        },
        {
            properties:"CBCharacteristicPropertyRead",
            value: [0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD],
            permissions:"CBAttributePermissionsReadable",
            UUID: "14A68648-2FC3-440D-AAA8-818FD73539A3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm parsing this using the following code (see complete version down below, I cut out the important bit for demonstration purposes):

```
NSMutableArray *characteristics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonService = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *serviceArgs = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonService options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary * characteristicsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
for (NSDictionary *characteristicArgs in [serviceArgs valueForKey:@"characteristics"]) {
    NSString *value = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"value"];
    NSString *props = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"properties"];
    NSString *permissions = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"permissions"];
    NSString *uuid = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"UUID"];

    //NSLog(@"Adding Characteristic: uuid=%@, properties=%@, value=\"%@\", permissions=%@", uuid, props, value,permissions);
    NSData *dataValue;
    if (value == (id)[NSNull null] || value.length == 0 ) {
        //NSLog(@"value is null!");
        dataValue = nil;
    }
    else
        dataValue = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //...
    //...
```

As you can see, I was using NSString before, but I had to change that, because the data conversion didn't work properly across browsers. Now I want to change the dataValue line to:

```
dataValue = [NSData dataWithBytes:value length:sizeof(value)];
```

but I'm not sure how to parse the data. I'm not entirely sure what kind of data-type I have to expect. So basically I need to know, what datatype my javascript array will be converted to (or how to tell NSJSONSerialization that it should parse into a char[]. It is really important to note that not all values will contain UTF8 data or any other type of common String data. It's just plain Byte-Code (so parsing directly into NSData would be the best option).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value is a NSArray, and each char is a NSNumber, so you can do something like this (I've simplified your code, you don't need all that conversions)

```
NSDictionary *serviceArgs = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

for (NSDictionary *characteristicArgs in [serviceArgs valueForKey:@"characteristics"]) {
    NSArray *values = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"value"];
    NSString *props = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"properties"];
    NSString *permissions = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"permissions"];
    NSString *uuid = [characteristicArgs objectForKey:@"UUID"];

    //NSLog(@"Adding Characteristic: uuid=%@, properties=%@, value=\"%@\", permissions=%@", uuid, props, values,permissions);

    for (NSNumber *value in values) {
        //here do domething with each char
    }

}
```